# Meteor Server Side Rendering in App

Tags: javascript, ios, meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I've recently got involved with Meteor.js. I have started building my app and am trying to decide whether to use Flowrouter, or React.Router.

I see that FlowRouter includes Server Side Rendering or SSR. Since I am primarily making a meteor app that will function on an iphone, and iPad are there any advantages / disadvantages to do SSR? Is it not needed / will it slow down animations or the app in general?

Answer (score 1):

FlowRouter SSR is still in beta, It's only for react for now, Blaze support is coming soon. So it's more of Blaze vs React question you can choose either one because SSR eventually will be for both of them. I personally use Blaze, It's great I don't really see the need to switch to React. Also in the future SSR can come from the meteor team as a core package and we probably won't need to use FlowRouter for it. SSR has really specific use cases so if you don't know if you need it you probably don't. SSR will be nice to improve speed (sometimes) and for SEO. But for now you don't really have to worry about it.

Comment: is there any update when Flow Router 4.0 with support for Blaze is coming? I have a high traffic app with around 200.000 links and it seems like phantomjs with spiderable are doing alright, but I guess SSR would be doing way better job.
I'm searching for it, but can't really find anything relevant.